# Detect the point of Android App close (when user swipe the app on recent screen, not go into background)

Tags: android, mixpanel

I have integrated Mixpanel and want to track the event when user close the app, just swipe the app on the recent screen.

set the breakpoints on onStop, onDestory, onPause and tried to debug.

To close the app, once i do long press on the home button, app breaks on onStop() function.
And i swiped the app to close, there wasnt any breaking.

How can i detect the event of App Closed? Which function do i need to put the code on?

I would appreciate if this is resolved.

Comment: Do you need the event of app being closed - meaning being terminated?

Comment: yes, when you close the app by swiping the app on recent screen.

do long press on home button, you can see recent apps, swipe the app, then app will be closed.
i just want to detect this moment.

Comment: Isnt that OnTerminate in your application class?

Comment: no, OnTerminate is not called when app is hard closed.